# What needs to be done (in steps) to launch a project

Tags: c#, asp.net, telegram, telegram-bot

I started the project (https://github.com/Sebreiro/TelegramBotMessageSender#Config) and entered the data that the author indicated but still an error - in order to debug it is necessary to add executable file to the project that refers to the library project

Comment: There is no question. You'll need to provide more information about what you have tried and try to narrow it down to specific problem. Maybe it's worth raising an issue in github for this project, however, it's not been updated for a year so maybe its no longer maintained.

Comment: hope you set TelegramBotMessageSender as a startup project.